# Objective-C if statement with AND

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm curious right now. Say that I have this part of the code:

```
NSError *serializationError;
NSData *errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey];
NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:errorData options:kNilOptions error:&serializationError];
if (!serializationError && [serializedData objectForKey:@"message"]) {
    toReturn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [serializedData objectForKey:@"message"]];
}
```

What I'm checking is if there is some serialization error and if there is objectForKey in that dictionary. IF there IS a serialization error, will this [serializedData objectForKey:@"message"] be performed? I know I can put if in if and never let the code get to this dictionary method, but I'm curious if it's gonna skip it if there is actually a serializationError?

Comment: `a && b` will not evaluate `b` if `a` is false. This is called [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it's part of virtually every language that supports boolean logic operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objectForKey:` will NOT be called if there is a serialization error. If you want it to always be called, put it before `!serializationError`.